# Is running SNMP v2c really insecure and can lead to compromisses?

Tags: network, snmp

I currently use SNMP v2c to monitor switches, servers, ect... to graph for performance. Question in terms of SNMP.

Everyone says that running SNMP insecure is a security risk. How is a graphing protocol designed to transmit messages insecure? Is the because the information could be tampered with or could provide information about the network?

Answer (score 5):

SNMP enables an attacker to paint the same graph you are painting. "These are the mission critical systems they're worried about. They must be if they're being monitored." Whenever I see SNMP during pentests, I get happy since it minimizes the amount of time I spend looking for this. SNMP has enabled me to find networks I would have otherwise not discovered, when systems (Windows, Linux) run SNMP, they allow me to see the software on the systems, the usernames, groups, patch levels. So yes SNMP can be a security risk.

If you must enable it, remember the fact that the same things you want to see, are invaluable to an attacker. With that in mind, it pays to define ACLs on your switch to allow specific machines to access SNMP. E.g.: "enable from this ONE machine to SNMP, and block all other connections." Then you have to worry about sniffing the network. This does not get into SNMP when configured to write. An attacker can modify a switch/router/system. Long story short, while it is a risk, it can be mitigated with proper ACLs, network segmentation/isolation.

Comment: Is SNMP always a risk or only the "insecure" v1 and v2 standards? From my understanding v3 is the recommended protocol to be using, since it utilizes message encryption, message integrity checks, as well as authentication.

Comment: SNMP v3 allow encryption, but setup are more complicated, i.e. authentication is required, and encryption handshaking definitely not as simple as v2. Also, SNMP agents may contains vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 2):

SNMP is not only a graphing protocol! SNMP requests can be used to find out more or less everything about a machine including host name, configured IP addresses, routing tables etc. You can also make configuration changes with SNMP when RW access is configured.

You should have a read about MIB databases and Object Identifiers to see how much information can be learned through SNMP requests. You should tighten up which machines are allowed to poll your SNMP enabled machines

Answer (score 1):

An attacker could know how are yours net devices and search vulnerabilities from them, if you use SNMPv2, you should be careful to permit only read access.